# How to handle database file in WP8 isolated storage?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have using database connection with WP8 in isolated storage.

I have created database and tables successfully.   But when i closed emulator, the database are not available in isolated storage.  e.g. I stored the data in employee.  After close and open the emulator,  there is no data in employee tables.

How will handle database in isolated storage?

I need the database file for long.

Any one assist me to handle this.

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Windows phone Emulator` is a `virtual Device` and it doesn't keep any track of Records. Every time when its closed Your Application is deleted so data is also. Again Starting a Emulator gives you a fresh `Isolated` in case of Emulator but in `Device` it is stored `till the application is not Uninstalled`. So try it in a Device it would not happen.